# Yii2 Ajax Request not working

Tags: php, ajax, http-status-code-404, yii2

I've been trying to use a widget that allows me to do dependent dropdown listswithout having to write any javascript on my own, but something isn't working and i'm pretty sure it has something to do with the url.

My Controller Action

```
public function actionGetMunicipiosList() {
    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
        $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        if ($parents != null) {
            $cat_id = $parents[0];
            $out = RegionMunicipios::getMunicipioList($cat_id);
            echo Json::encode(['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>'']);
            return;
        }
    }
    echo Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'selected'=>'']);
}
```

Function that I'm calling from another model

```
public function getMunicipioList($cat_id){
    $muni = RegionMunicipios::find()->where(['estados_id' => $cat_id])->asArray()->all();
    $data = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($muni, 'id', 'descripcion');
    /*foreach ($muni as $i => $m) {
        $data[] = ['id' => $m['id'], 'name' => $m['descripcion']];
    }*/
    return $data;
}
```

My View's Parent Dropdown

```
<?= 
    Select2::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'estados_id',
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(RegionEstados::find()->all(),'id','descripcion'),
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Seleccione', 
            'id'=>'regionparroquias-estados_id'
        ],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
    ])
?>
```

My View's Second Dropdown

```
<?= 
$form->field($model, 'municipios_id')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'type'=>DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
    #'data'=>ArrayHelper::map(RegionMunicipios::find()->where(['estados_id' => $model->estados->id])->all(),'id','descripcion'),
    'options'=>[
        'id'=>'regionparroquias-municipios_id', 
        'placeholder'=>'Seleccione'
    ],
    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'depends'=>[Html::getInputId($model, 'estados_id')],
            'url'=>Url::to(['?r=region-estados/GetMunicipiosList']),
            'loadingText'=>'Cargando...',
            'initialize'=>($model->isNewRecord) ? false : true,
        ]
    ]
);
?>
```

I've tried to do this with yii2 basic and the yii2 practical boilerplate that can be found on github, but the result is the same.
With the url like that it just throws error 404.
When i append the prefix '?r=' to the url parameter it actually seems to find the controller action, but it really doesn't, because i tried using the name of another controller which doesn't exist and no error was thrown.

And by the way I'm using namespaces of the extensions or models that I need to use at the top of the files where i need to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update (11/3/2014)**

The problem with camel case action names is addressed as a backward compatablity [issue within yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5029).
When you define a controller action named `actionSayHelloWorld` you can only call it in the url with a hypenated id: `<conroller name>/say-hello-world`.

====================================

I experience some problems with the name giving an calling of controller actions myself.
When my controller `Person` has action `actionGreetHelloWord`, I cannot call it from the url, it will always result in 404. However, when I change the action name to `actionGreethelloworld`, I can call it form the url with `person/greethelloworld` (all lowercase including the g of greet).

So I think your problem will be solved when you change the action name to `Getmunicipioslist` and create the url with/as:

`'url'=>Url::to('region-estados/getmunicipioslist'),`
or
`'url'=>\yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('region-estados/getmunicipioslist'),`

To avoid to much work, you can first change the action name in your controller and type the url (`.../region-estados/getmunicipioslist'`) for the controller and action in the address bar and if that works, do the changes in your view.

*I do not know if yii by default can find controllers with a `-` in its name.*

Comment: it still won't find the controller's action. I;m really disappointed in yii 2. I think after I'm done with my projects in yii 1 i'll just start using laravel

Comment: Oh thanks Barry. I didn't think of that before. It works, it makes sense (since we have to hyphenate the controller's name anyway),and I can still camel case the names of my actions. I still don't get why they decided to change this stuff in yii2, but at least it works. Thank you very much for the update.

Answer (score 1):

well i figured out that Yii2 will validate it like this:

actionGetMunicipiosList => get-municipios-list

hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you were really onto something here. I was about to give up on Yii2... I still have my doubts about it but i guess i'll use it if i ever need to.

I changed the name of the controller action to 
`Getmunicipioslist`

and call it like as `Url::to(['region-estados/getmunicipioslist'])`

Still I don't think it makes much sense to not let people camelize function names, we do it for a reason, it makes our code more readable by others AND ourselves, but whatever.

Thanks.